# Homeomorphism between punctured disk and circle

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

Is there a homeomorphism between the circle $S^1$ and the punctured disk $D^2 \setminus \{p\}$, $p\in D^2$ ?

Intuitively it seems that when you puncture the disk you can then deform it into a circle but I can't see how this would be done.

Comment: There is not.  Remove an additional two points to see why.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, the two spaces can't be homeomorphic.  $S^1$ is compact but the punctured disk is not.  Also, you can disconnnect $S_1$ by removing two points, but that's not possible for the punctured disc.

You can continuously deform the punctured disc to get $S_1$ by using the retraction mapping:  Just walk every point in the punctured disc away from the center along a radius until you reach the boundary.